# Python code to sum the square values of numbers from 1 to n

Tags: python, sum, square

I am struggling to add numbers by using python. Could you please aid me. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the addition operator `+` or the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function

Comment: i dont want to use the sum function. Also if i have like 300 numbers i can add them individually

Comment: What have you tried? Have you familiarized yourself with basic Python syntax yet? This is an extremely elementary question that I'm sure can be resolved with a little work to learn the bare minimum elements of the language.

Comment: doing so as we speak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would do it in Python 2:

```
n = int(raw_input("Type n:"))
total = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    total += i**2
print total
```

Here is how you would do it in Python 3:

```
n = int(input("Type n:"))
total = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    total += i**2
print(total)
```

This takes the numbers 1 through `n` and put them into variable `i`.  For each time this happens, it takes the square of `i` and adds it onto `total`.  It then prints the total.

I suggest reading a Python book.  "Hello World" by Carter and Warren Sande is a fantastic one!

If you need further clarification, notify me in the comments.